# Could I ask an employee of my company's client for a recommendation letter ? Will it violate any company policy?

Tags: company-policy, clients, recommendation-letter, company-norms

I will be applying to Graduate schools for Fall 2019. I have taken my GRE and will be planning to take again. My undergrad core GPA is not very good due to health problems, which I will mention in my statement of purpose (admissions essay). I read that letters of recommendation are very important if you want to get into a good college especially to offset my low GPA.

I work full time as a Team Lead at a software company specifically on a contract with a very huge software company "BIM".  To "BIM", I am a contractor, but involved fully in software programming and development. The people I work with at "BIM" are scientists and the best kind of people to write letters of recommendation.

My manager is okay with me approaching the scientist a letter of recommendation, but my Project Manager is not. Apparently the Project Manager believes it will create "chaos" and it would make "BIM" scientists uneasy.

I have emailed HR as to whether it is against company policy and am waiting a reply. Should I go ahead and request the "BIM" scientists directly for a letter of recommendation?

Comment: We can't tell you if it would violate any company policy, because we do not know the policies of the two involved companies.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity and expanded the abbreviations for people not familiar with the graduate school terms.

Answer (score 2):

Wait for HR to respond.

If you go ahead with it and HR says you shouldn't have, you could get fired from your company or let go as a contractor from your client and that will basically torpedo any chances you have of getting a LOR from either.